# Redirect Domain to Specific Page on Another Domain (htaccess)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to redirect an entire website to a specific page on another website, like so:

`redirect 301 / http://www.somewebsite.co.uk/some-page.php/`

It is sending me to the new website successfully when I visit the old domain, but when I visit an internal page off the old domain then I get a 404 on the new domain.

So something like `olddomain.com/some-old-page.htm` would send me to a 404 on `somewebsite.co.uk`

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `RedirectMatch` directive like this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^ http://www.somewebsite.co.uk/some-page.php/
```

Make sure this is very first line in your .htaccess